# CORS error: Response to preflight request The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header contains multiple values '*, *',

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, cors

I am creating an angularjs UI CMS and using php for the backend connection. On the php script I have added the following headers:
 `header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");`
`header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");`

On the angularjs side, I am using $ajax to call the APIs in each controller, using the following code:

`$.ajax({type : 'GET', url : 'https://.../get_city_tokens.php?city_token=' + $location.search().id, contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',dataType: 'json' ,success: function(response) {console.log(response)}});`

The error I receive is the following:

*Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://worldcitytrail.com/WCT_online/get_city_tokens.php?city_token=YYf727XkGL2L8CeX' from origin 'http://localhost' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header contains multiple values '*, *', but only one is allowed.*

I have searched the angular.js project in order to find where the "" header is in other files, however I see that I haven't set anywhere else these headers.

Could please anyone help?

Answer (score -1):

It looks like a server side problem.
There are several values specified in the settings for the header "'Access-Control-Allow-Origin". There should be one for example:

1. add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
2. add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' 'http://localhost:3000' always;

always needed in order to add a header in case of errors from the server.

Here's another example  https://enable-cors.org/server_nginx.html